# Using cupy instead of numpy in xgboost training significantly lowered test-auc score

Tags: python, numpy, xgboost, cupy

**Backgroud**:

- Try to run xgboost model on GPU instead of CPU.
- Use cupy to replace numpy for better GPU speedup.

**Problems**:

- when using numpy format, my test-AUC is above 0.77
- when using cupy format, my test-AUC is around 0.5

**Sample Codes**:

```
import xgboost as xgb
import pandas as pd

X_train=pd.read_pickle('X_train.pkl')
X_test=pd.read_pickle('X_val.pkl')
y_train=pd.read_pickle('y_train.pkl')
y_test=pd.read_pickle('y_val.pkl')
```

### using numpy.ndarray

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train.values, label=y_train.values)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test.values, label=y_test.values)

num_boost_round = 1000
early_stopping_rounds=100
params = {
    'max_depth':11,
    'min_child_weight': 7,
    'eta':.1,
    'subsample': 1,
    'colsample_bytree': .8,
    'eval_metric': 'auc',
    'objective':'binary:logistic',
    #GPU enabled
    'gpu_id': 0,
    'tree_method':'gpu_hist',

}
model = xgb.train(
    params,
    dtrain,
    num_boost_round=num_boost_round,
    evals=[(dtrain,'Train'),(dtest, "Test")],
    early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
    verbose_eval = 50
)

# output
# Stopping. Best iteration:
# [999] Train-auc:0.84847   Test-auc:0.77523
```

### using cupy.ndarray

```
import cupy
# convert to cupy
X_train_cp = cupy.array(X_train.values)
y_train_cp = cupy.array(y_train.values)
X_test_cp = cupy.array(X_test.values)
y_test_cp = cupy.array(y_test.values)

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train_cp, label=y_train_cp)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test_cp, label=y_test_cp)

num_boost_round = 1000
early_stopping_rounds=100
params = {
    'max_depth':11,
    'min_child_weight': 7,
    'eta':.1,
    'subsample': 1,
    'colsample_bytree': .8,
    'eval_metric': 'auc',
    'objective':'binary:logistic',
    #GPU enabled
    'gpu_id': 0,
    'tree_method':'gpu_hist',
}
model = xgb.train(
    params,
    dtrain,
    num_boost_round=num_boost_round,
    evals=[(dtrain,'Train'),(dtest, "Test")],
    early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
    verbose_eval = 50
)

# output
# Stopping. Best iteration:
# [182] Train-auc:0.58999   Test-auc:0.50665

# check values 
X_train_np = cupy.asnumpy(X_train_cp)
(X_train_np == X_train.values).all()
    
#output
True
```

xgb version = '**1.2.1**'
cupy version = '**8.1.0**'
and i'm running this test on kaggle.
Let me know if more information needed, i can provide the train and test data.

Comment: for those who might have same problem. here is the github trace of the bug. and this bug is supposed to be fixed on xgboost 1.3.0 release. https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/6454